# Algorithm - Find the center index

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum, big-o

Given an array of ints with size `t`, one needs to find the center index. The center index `x` is  the index where the sum of ints (0 to x-1) is equal to sum (x+1 to t-1).

The best algorithm I could come up with is O(n).

I would have a temp array with the sums of all ints before (not including the one at index x) : so at index 1 it would be 1, at 2 it would be a sum of 2 and 1 and so on.

Another int would be the sum of all ints.

I would loop twice through the array, the first make the temp array, and the other to find if both parts are equal.

Is there a better algorithm O(logn)?

Comment: What is `x`? Is the size you mention at the end of your first paragraph `t`? Review the paragraph and see if you can make it clearer.

Comment: X is the index i am looking for, t is the size of the array

Comment: I don't think, I can do better than O(n), but space required can be made O(1). Two accumulators for storing sum from top and sum from bottom. Start with two pointers pointing at index 0 and last. Increment top pointer or decrement bottom pointer based on `sum_from_top > sum_from_bottom`.

Comment: @Vikas, sorry, I didn't get it. the array is unsorted and it could have negative elements. how can you find the x using two pointers? can you explain it in more detail in an answer?

Comment: @Kent, I did not think of negative numbers in array. If we have only non-negative numbers in the array, even if they are not sorted, then it can be solved with two pointers and two accumulators. Because in this case sum of numbers will always be a non-decreasing sequence.

Comment: @Vikas: the method with two accumulators looks correct to me if the algorithm is modified to loop through every index without breaking, and outputting every x such that x is a "center index". However, there can be many of them. If the array contains only zeros, then every index is a center index. There could also be no center index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have to calculate the sum of both the half of the array, this can't be solved in less than `O(n)`. Because you have to inspect each element at least once (to calculate the sum). Any algorithm can be `logn` only if we can skip inspecting certain elements of the array based on some condition which is not possible here.

Comment: One possible implementation I did in C with O(n) time & O(1) space complexity: http://ideone.com/XRaE8

Comment: This solution is exactly what i mentioned in my comment. And as others pointed out, it won't work if there are negative numbers in array.